# Script loads 20 secrets from keyvault at init - Returns throttling error

Tags: node.js, azure-keyvault

In my node app, I use "azure-keyvault" and "ms-rest-azure" npm packages to load 20 secrets from the keyvault into the environment variables `process.env`. When starting the application it fails with an error:

> Error: Invalid token response, did not find tokenType. Response body is: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Temporarily throttled, too many requests"}
>       at Request.request.get [as _callback] (/app/node_modules/ms-rest-azure/lib/credentials/msiVmTokenCredentials.js:52:17)
>       at Request.self.callback (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
>       at Request. (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at IncomingMessage. (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
>       at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)

My approach is to get an access token (either via service principal or MSI, depending on whether I run locally or within Azure), then use it to query key vault for secrets.

MS has docs regarding request throttling, which basically a keyvault can do 2000 secret transations in every 10s intervall. Obviously I am nowhere near this limit.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#secrets-managed-storage-account-keys-and-vault-transactions

Also what is funny: I have not problem when running it locally. It just now throws errors when I try to run it within a VM in Azure.

Someone also experienced this yet?

Here's the code

```js
import {ApplicationTokenCredentials, MSIVmTokenCredentials, loginWithServicePrincipalSecret, loginWithMSI} from 'ms-rest-azure';
import {KeyVaultClient} from 'azure-keyvault';

export class Env {

    public static getAccessToken(): Promise<ApplicationTokenCredentials> {
        // use service principal when running locally because MSI is not available here  
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'remote') {
            return loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(process.env.SP_ID, process.env.SP_SEC, process.env.SP_TEN);
        } else { // remote
            return loginWithMSI({resource: 'https://vault.azure.net'});
        }
    }
    
    public static getSecret(credentials: MSIVmTokenCredentials, secretName: string): Promise<string> {
        let client = new KeyVaultClient(credentials);
        const keyVaultUrl: string = `https://${process.env.VAULT_NAME}.vault.azure.net`;
        return client.getSecret(keyVaultUrl, secretName, "").then(secret => secret.value);
    }

    public static decodeBase64(base64: string) { return Buffer.from(base64, 'base64').toString("utf8"); }
}
```

```js
import * as express from 'express';
import {
  Env
} from './env';

class Server {

  // set app to be of type express.Application
  public app: express.Application;

  constructor() {
    this.app = express();
    this._setEnvs().then(() => {
      this._config();
      this._routes();
      this._startReminderCronJob();
    });
  }

  private _setEnvs(): Promise < void > {
    return Env.getAccessToken()
      .then(token => {
        return Promise.all([
          Env.getSecret(token, 'my-secret'),
          ...
          Env.getSecret(token, 'another-secret'),
        ])
      }).then(secrets => {
        process.env.SECRET_1 = secrets[0];
        ...
        process.env.SECRET_20 = secrets[19];
      }).catch(err => console.log(err)); // error is logged here
  }

  private _config(): void {}

  private _routes(): void {}

  private _startReminderCronJob(): void {}
}

export default new Server().app;
```

Comment: I reworked the code. Instead of chaining promises, I went with async/await and now it works. :o Is there an explanation for this? I assumed both approaches regarding promises were identical.

Comment: That's good, you can also try https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-azure-secrets which will return all secrets from the key vault